# restricting android application dimensions on screen

Tags: android

when i launch my application on android os this is occupying the entire available screen. This is not desired. i want my app only to occupy portion of the screen say a rectangle of "10,10,100,100". so how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the dialog theme for a single Activity, by declaring the theme in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" android:name="your.package.and.ActivityName"/>
```

This will make your [`Activity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) look like a [`Dialog`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html).

Comment: Hi  now this appears as a dialoge with the dimensions of root layout. It is appaering in the center of the screen and even when i drag that it is not moving. how can i make it move?

Comment: Moving the layout is a different question and a tricky task, since it's not supported out of the box. Check the [Dialog documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html) for modification of the Dialog's size.

Comment: So one last question. when we use dialog theme. The top most container is the dialog and the layouts will be drawn on the dialog. Is my understanding right?

Comment: The Dialog is a [Window](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html) of it's own and the Layouts will be drawn in the Dialog's Window.